# kendogrid batch edit appending row causes to post data

Tags: datagrid, kendo-ui

This code populates datagrid with json formated data received from /api/notes/ by tornado app...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    pageSize: 10,
    autoSync: true,
    transport: {
      read: {
        url: '/api/notes/',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET'
      },
      create: {
        url: '/api/notes/',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST'
      },
      update: {
        url: '/api/notes/',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'PUT'
      }
    },
    schema: {
      data: function(reply) { return reply.rows; },
      model: {
        id: "id",
        fields: {
          id: { type: "string" },
          name: { type: "string" },
          author: { type: "string" },
        }
      }
    },
  });

  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    navigatable: true,
    pageable: true,
    height: 300,
    editable: true,
    toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
    columns: [
      { field: "id", title: "ID", width: 150 },
      { field: "name", title: "Book", width: 150 },
      { field: "author", title: "Author", width: 100 },
      { command: "destroy", title: "&nbsp;", width: 110 }
    ],
  });

});
```

if I click create instead of popping up a row, like [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing.html) a post triggered with empty `data` parameter, what's wrong here

Answer (score 1):

Try it with `autoSync` removed or set to `false` on the `DataSource`. According to the docs:

> Enables (true) or disables (false) the automatic invocation of the sync() method for each change made.

So I think when you try to insert the row, it immediately puts it into the DataSource, causing it to do a `sync()`. The demo you linked to doesn't specify `autoSync` either.